# Setup Program for Windows Service C# How to add Sql Database's

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation

I've written on visual studio 2010 a windows service. I create all database on vs2010, where I've created a setup program for windows service to install it. My problem is I can not put my database to setup program, so that my windows service gives error on sql-database's. (At debug mode there are no problems, win. service works fine)

How can I fix this or what do I miss ?

Comment: Hm, not enough information to figure out what this is asking or what the problem is...

Comment: I have a setup program but my MsSql database is not installed with the setup program. My setup program only install the program without the Sql-Database.

Answer (score 1):

You only have the right to redistribute SQL Server Express, see [Distributing SQL Server Express](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165639%28SQL.90%29.aspx). This is typically achieved by embeding the SQL Server Express install in the applicaiton distirbution Setup, see [Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb264562). For every other version of SQL Server the customer running your application must purchase a SQL Server license and install it, or configure your application to run with an existing instalation.